# Using Python and Opencv, how do I convert Umat back to mat?

Tags: python, opencv, opencl, mat

My project is written in python 3.6, and I'm using [opencv](https://opencv.org/) and [fast.ai](https://www.fast.ai/).

I'm trying to determine if Umat can outperform mat for some live video analysis. I have code that works to detect objects in a frame of video, and then get a bounding box. I crop the image, and then pass it off to a neural network.

The time taken to process each frame of video on my cpu is about 23 milliseconds.

I would like to try using Umat to see if it can be done faster. However, before the image can be fed into the neural network, it needs to be converted back to something that fastai understands. The following code works with regular mat images. If I were to pass `frame` instead of `uframe` to `cv2.Umat()`, the code works perfectly.

```
# get a frame of video and make a Umat out of it.
frame = video.read()
uframe = cv2.UMat(frame)

# Do stuff to uframe; grayscale, background subtraction, get object coordinates.  

# crop the image. 
cropped_image = cv2.UMat(uframe, [[x1:x2],[y1:y2]])

# color space conversion for fastai compatibility
swapped_image = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# convert to fastai Image class
fastai_image = Image(pil2tensor(swapped_image, dtype=np.float32).div_(255))

# Send fastai_image image to neural network.
```

However, when I run the code as shown above, (passing `Uframe` to `cv2.Umat()`), the code fails at `fastai_image = Image(pil2tensor()`, with an exception:

```
ValueError: axes don't match array
```

I know this error is related to how the axis data is stored, but I'm not sure what to do about it. I would like to either convert the image back to a mat, or possibly alter the axis data of the Umat. Does anyone know the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: `cv2.UMat.get(swapped_image)`

Comment: That works, thanks! Unfortunately, it seems to run about he same speed so far, but I'll keep tinkering with it to see if I can improve it.

Comment: Yeah, there's probably too little work being done on the `UMat`, so whatever you may save on the color conversion is lost in the overhead of moving the data to/from `UMat`.